# Why is working with material on eevee so slow?

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I have been moving to Blender 2.8 and am really impressed by how accessible the software got now. Initially it also was quite responsive and swift, but for some reasons I am running into trouble lately. Working with materials in general and with the BSDF Shader in particular became so sluggish recently and sometimes the system completely locks up even in absolutely basic scenes in Eevee.

The first days I could render scenes in an instant, but now Windows 10 does often not respond any longer.

I had re-installed 2.8 already, but no change.

My system is an Intel Core i5-3470 CPU, 3.20 GHz
16 GM RAM
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti

I am sorry, if this has been asked before, but I am researching for weeks now and still couldn't find anything similar regarding 2.8. It seems there had been such an issue on 2.79, but not for 2.8.

Thanks in advance for any hint in the right direction.

Comment: Your system should handle Eevee like a charm. I've got the same config but with only a 560Ti and it works fine. Maybe something is wrong with you GPU drivers ? Did you tried it under Linux ? (Don't install a full Linux, just boot on some Ubuntu live usb)

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. That's a relief to hear the system should be sufficient. Good point, maybe it really is related to the GPU drivers. I will have a try and also look into this Ubuntu idea. Thanks again!